# How to count frequency of multiple variables within a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

I am looking for a way to summarize a table in such a way as I have a count of the number of times a variable appears, grouped by a second variable. Below is what my data looks like:

| group | excellent |
| --- | --- |
| A | Yes |
| B | No |
| B | No |
| C | No |
| C | No |
| C | Yes |
| D | No |
| D | Yes |

and I would like to get something like this that shows the count of each group.

| Excellent | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| No | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

I've tried as.data.frame, tally, table, and nothing is having the outcome I need.

Comment: `"I've tried as.data.frame, tally, table..."` - please share your codes.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Load the necessary library if not already loaded
library(reshape2)

# Create your data frame
data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
  excellent = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
)

# Create a contingency table
table_data <- table(data)

# Reshape the table
melted_data <- melt(table_data)

# Use dcast to get the desired format
result <- dcast(melted_data, excellent ~ group, value.var = "value", fill = 0)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
  excellent A B C D
1        No 0 2 2 1
2       Yes 1 0 1 1
```

This table shows the count of each group for "Excellent" with "Yes" and "No" as the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table`

```
> t(table(df))
         group
excellent A B C D
      No  0 2 2 1
      Yes 1 0 1 1
```

or `aggregate` + `reshape` to make a data frame

```
reshape(
    aggregate(
        cnt ~ .,
        transform(
            df,
            cnt = 1
        ),
        sum
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "excellent",
    timevar = "group"
)
```

which gives

```
  excellent cnt.B cnt.C cnt.D cnt.A
1        No     2     2     1    NA
4       Yes    NA     1     1     1
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"
), excellent = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No",
"Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` & `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  summarize(n = n(), .by = c(group, excellent)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   excellent     A     B     C     D
#>   <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 Yes           1     0     1     1
#> 2 No            0     2     2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>